# How to ident the cursor to the indentation of the above line?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode, macos

I want to move the cursor to the indentation of the line above.

As seen from the example below, when I move the cursor down (`j` or `arrow-down`), it goes to the start of the line. This is both true for insert and normal mode.

However, if I'm in normal mode and press `o` to insert a line below the current line, then Vim knows it should move the cursor to the indentation of the line above.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make sense to go to the "indent" column while in Normal mode. You can "keep column" in Normal mode with `set virtualedit=all`, and you can also start editing on "indent" column with `S` or `cc`.

Comment: @Matt - `S` and `cc` deletes the line for me? `set virtualedit=all` doesn't go to the indentation level, i.e. `fmt.Println(..)` in my GIF.

Comment: @Shuzheng Matt means press `S` or `cc` when you are on the blank line. The problem is, as Matt suggests, there is nothing there for the cursor to be on, but there will be spaces/tabs inserted when entering insert mode (in some cases). `set list listchars^=trail:.` is useful for seeing this. `virtualedit` allows your cursor to move even where there is not text

Comment: Do you really want to be at that position in Normal mode or is your intention to start adding text immediately after navigation? If the latter than you could just use a mapping like, for example, `nnoremap <leader>j ^y0jpa`. (That's a quick approach that works if the next line is really blank...ie. not filled with whitespace.)

Comment: @BLayer - I want to start adding text immediately after navigation. Why does pressing `o` on the above line suit my needs, when I can’t find other ways to achieve the same result without adding an extra empty line?

Comment: @BLayer - can you describe what your mapping does exactly?

Comment: It goes to first non-blank char `^`, yanks from there to first column `y0` (presumably spaces and/or tabs), navigates down one line `j`, pastes the indentation `p`, starts insert mode `a`. There are other ways to do the same..nothing too much shorter. Why isn't there a native, one char command to do this?  Not sure. (I'm assuming there isn't but even I get surprised now and then.)

Comment: When you're on empty line press `S` to start inserting with respect to the previous line indent; when you're on non-empty line press `I` to start inserting just after the (existing) indent.

Comment: @Matt - it doens't work for me? The cursor doesn't move, if I press `S` or `I` in normal mode on an empty line. Both commands simply enter insert mode.

Comment: @BLayer - what the difference between `nnoremap` and `noremap`? I've already consulted `:help noremap`, but it doesn't describe their differences. I'm used to use `noremap`.

Comment: These are stanard commands. They **must** work unless you've remapped them.

Comment: @Matt - `help S` says: "Delete [count] lines [into register x] and insert.  Synonym for "cc" |linewise|." Nothing is mentioned about indentation.

Comment: Did you try to read `:h cc`?

Comment: @matt In my installation of Vim (8.1.2234), with `autoindent` or `smartindent` set, `cc` will _not_ insert indent on an empty line, even though pressing `o` on the line above does insert the indent. This is consistent with the documentation, which states that `cc` will preserve the indent of the (first) replaced line. (With `cindent`, `cc` _does_ insert indent when used on an empty line).

Comment: @Rich There (in python) indentation is ruled by `indentexpr`. The latter is due to `GetPythonIndent()` from `indent/python.vim`. Try to type `if 1:` and then `S` on the next empty line - it will do indent the same as `o`. So it's a filetype-indent-plugin-dependent thing. So what question should we answer? Normal mode mapping seems useless to me; writing a new indentexpr - does it worth it?

Comment: @Matt The code in the gif isn't Python.

Comment: @Rich And what is that? Go? (Btw. it's indentexpr too). Perhaps, someone should set the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `o` works the way it does is that, with `autoindent` or `smartindent` set, it will *insert* whitespace in order to match the indentation of the previous line.

When you move downwards in normal mode without entering insert mode, the line remains empty and no text is added, so the cursor moves to the start of the line.

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to:

1. Accept the fact that when you move to an empty line in normal mode the cursor will move to the start of the line, and
2. Use a more sophisticated method of auto indentation, and start editing the line by typing either `S` or `cc`. For the language in your screenshot (Go?) [`'cindent'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cindent%27) should work fine, and when it is set `S` or `cc` on an empty line will insert indent as you desire, but even better than this would be to use Vim's included [`'indentexpr'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27indentexpr%27) for this language. You can do this by allowing Vim to set up indentation when it sets the [filetype](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#filetype), which you can achieve by adding the following line to your `.vimrc`:

   ```
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```

   With this in place, `'indentexpr'` will be set to `GoIndent(v:lnum)` when you start editing a Go file, and using `cc` or `S` on an empty line will insert the appropriate indent.

See [`:help 30.3`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_30.txt.html#30.3) for more details on automatic indenting.

Comment: @Rich - yes, the language is Go. I haven’t used `indentexpr` or `cindent` in my .vimrc. Why is it better than `cindent`?

Comment: @Shuzheng You don’t need to set `indentexpr` yourself. You just need to allow Vim to set it automatically with the filetype command I suggested. `indentexpr` is better than `cindent` because it is specifically tailored for whichever language you are using. `cindent` is designed for `C` so it will work in places where Go syntax is the same as C but will fail when there are differences.

Comment: @Rich - thanks for this! I can’t believe that such indentation is not the default behavior.

Comment: @Rich - reading the documentation for `filetype plugin indent on` nothing is mentioned of `indentexpr` - why is that?

Comment: @Shuzheng Possibly you just missed it? At the end of `:h filetype-indent-on`, there's a link to `:h indent-expression` which explains and links to `:h 'indentexpr'`.